# How to turn FindFit result into function within a Module context

Tags: function-construction, fitting, scoping, expression-construction

I'm trying to construct a 'normal' function (with formal parameter) from the FindFit result within a Module context.

While this works on a global level:

In :=

```
points = Table[{x, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 4 + RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10}];
model = a x^2 + b x + c;
fit = FindFit[points, model, {a, b, c}, x];
f[x_] = Evaluate[model /. fit];
f[2]
```

Out :=

```
18.473
```

the same trick in a Module doesn't work.

In :=

```
Module[{points, model, fit, a, b, c, x, f},
 points = Table[{x, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 4 + RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10}];
 model = a x^2 + b x + c;
 fit = FindFit[points, model, {a, b, c}, x];
 f[x_] = Evaluate[model /. fit];
 f[2]
]
```

Out :=

```
4.1934 + 3.25034 x$30780002 + 1.97626 x$30780002^2
```

Looks that the trick with `Evaluate` doesn't work in a Module context - the argument `x` of the `f` is a new variable that is unurelated to the module-scoped `x`. I would not expect it to work even on a global level. Yet it works.

**So the question/problem is:** how to get the same effect in Modules in a Wolfram-idiomatic way?

Maybe I've missed the essence of Modules. I just want to protect the outside world from any leakage of assigned variables via lexical scoping, because I found that it is too easy to mess the global environment and destroy symbolical computations in unrelated parts of the script.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[f]

f[x_] = Module[
   {points, model, fit, a, b, c, x = x, f},
   (* x=x equates the function's argument to the Module's local \
variable *)
   SeedRandom[1234];
   points =
    Table[
     {x, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 4 + RandomReal[]},
     {x, 1, 10}];
   model = a x^2 + b x + c;
   fit = FindFit[points, model, {a, b, c}, x];
   model /. fit];

f[2]

(* 18.5393 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue here is that the `x` in `f[x]` is another local variable, different than the one in `Module`. To solve this in such cases I typically use patterns, like

```
 Module[{points, model, fit, a, b, c, x, f}, 
 points = Table[{x, 2 x^2 + 3 x + 4 + RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10}];
 model = a x^2 + b x + c;
 fit = FindFit[points, model, {a, b, c}, x];
 f[xx_] = model /. fit /. x -> xx;
 f[2]]
```

This works fine, but I am really looking forward for someone to suggests a more elegant solution, if it exists...